# Change Span Check Icon As Save Icon

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome, favicon

```
<style>   
 .ui-icon-check:before { content: ""; }
</style>
```

I want to change check button with fa fa-save icon. How can I do

my html code block is

```
<a href="#" class="ui-row-editor-pencil" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span></a>
<a href="#" class="ui-row-editor-check"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-c"></span></a>
::before
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-c"></span>
::before
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check ui-c"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I handle

```
.ui-row-editor-check:before {
content: "\f0C7";
content: "\f0c7";
font-family: FontAwesome;
/* font-style: normal; */
/* font-weight: normal; */
/* text-decoration: inherit; */
/* color: #000; */
font-size: 18px;
/* padding-right: 0.5em; */
/* position: absolute; */
top: 10px;
left: 0;
/* font-family: "Font Awesome 5"; */
```

}